# Problem with interfacing Cirus OS1 oxygen sensor with Arduio Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am trying to interface Arduino UNO with Cirus OS1 oxygen sensor but not able to get the expected output. The expected voltage output of OS1 sensor is 9-13mV and the oxygen % is expected to be in the range 19-21 %.

I am using the code :

```cpp
void setup()

{

     Serial.begin(9600);
     analogReference(INTERNAL);
}

void loop()
{

     const float A_REF = 1.1e3;
     const float Sensor_Cal = 1 / 0.6;
     int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
     float voltage = sensorValue *(A_REF / 1024);
     float oxygen = voltage * Sensor_Cal;
     Serial.print(" Voltage in mV : ");
     Serial.print(voltage);
     Serial.print("  ");
     Serial.print(" Oxygen level in % : ");
     Serial.println(oxygen);
     delay(1000);
}
```

However, I am getting an output :

[image]

I am using Cirus OS1 oxygen sensor - https://www.biometriccables.in/collections/oxygen-sensors/products/oxygen-sensor-os1

Expected voltage range - 9mV to 13mV
Expected oxygen % - 19 to 21 %
Have tried using LM324N opamp, but it's still not giving expected output. Kindly help or suggestions are welcome.